# QUnit terminates when function with arg throws unless wrapped in anon function

Tags: javascript, testing, anonymous-function, qunit

I am using QUnit to test a function which throws an error in the case of invalid inputs. I *am* able to test this function by embedding it within an anonymous function, but am unsure why this is necessary. If I don't do this, QUnit reports:

```
Died on test #4     at http://localhost:8000/qunit/throwsTest.js:1:7: sometimesThrows
```

Notably, this message *includes* the thrown error.

I have also noticed that I can make functions that don't require args work if I pass the function as an argument rather than invoke it.

Check out [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wws44ewp/) to see it live.

```
QUnit.test("throws test", function(assert) {
  function alwaysThrows() { throw "alwaysThrows"; }

  function sometimesThrows(foo) {
    if (foo) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      throw "sometimesThrows";
    }
  }

  assert.throws(alwaysThrows, "alwaysThrows throws (works)")

  assert.ok(sometimesThrows(true), "sometimesThows doesn't throw (works)");
  assert.throws(function() {
    sometimesThrows(false);
  }, "sometimesThrows throws inside anonymous function (works)");

  // Where the unexpected behavior occurs.
  // The error _is_ being thrown being thrown.
  assert.throws(sometimesThrows(false), "sometimesThrows throws (terminates)");

});
```

If wrapping the function to be tested in an anonymous function is the intended method for getting this to work, if someone could explain *why*, I would find that illuminating in developing my intuition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: This is exactly how the [`throws()` assertion in QUnit](http://api.qunitjs.com/throws/) is intended to work, and how it must work.

Long, drawn out response:

In your example you are calling the assertion with the **result** of the call to `sometimesThrows(false)`. That is to say, in your example above, when you call the QUnit assert method (`assert.throws()`) you pass in two values: the **return value from `sometimesThrows()` and a string message**.

In other words, your example:

```
assert.throws(sometimesThrows(false), "sometimesThrows throws (terminates)");
```

is first *first* calling the `sometimesThrows()` method with the `false` argument, which *executes* that method immediately, thus throwing an error. But where does that error go?? The fact is, that error is thrown from your method (`sometimesThrows()`) *directly into* the `test()` that you've written, bypassing entirely the `assert.throws()` call. In other words, the `assert.throws()` function call will never happen as an error was thrown prior to it being called in the execution flow.

Instead, we must pass the `assert.throws()` function yet another function which it can then *wrap* in a `try...catch` block to detect whether or not an error was thrown. We could separate this out and actually pass a named function in if you prefer (versus an anonymous, inline function), but that really doesn't change anything:

QUnit.test("throws test", function(assert) {
    // ..

```
function sometimesWrapper() {
    sometimesThrows(false);
}

assert.throws(sometimesWrapper, "sometimesThrows throws (terminates)");
```

});

Note that we do not *call* `sometimesWrapper()`, we pass it in as an argument to the `throws()` assertion method. Internally, QUnit will then wrap the actually *calling* of the `sometimesWrapper()` in a `try...catch` block so that it can determine whether the assertion passed or failed. You can see this in the [source code on Github](https://github.com/jquery/qunit/blob/master/src/assert.js#L164) if you wish.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks so much for clarifying the behavior!